Movie about an ex-convict who goes on a killing spree
I'm looking for a movie I watched a few years ago. The spoken language was English. From what I remember, the movie is from between 2005-2014:
The movie starts with the ex-convict leaving jail, and meeting a woman in a pink car to drive him to his hometown (somewhere in the USA). He wants to go back to his former girlfriend/wife, of whom he was separated due to a failed robbery. At some point he is driving a muscle car. 
The man goes on a killing spree, killing many people who are with the new guy that has his ex wife under control. At some point he reaches the house where she is being kept, although she lost her mind completely. 
The movie features a lot of violence, drug usage and if I remember correctly alcohol usage as well. He is faced with a lot of déjà vus, in which you see his ex girlfriend and him being happy. 
No famous actors, not the typical AAA title. The ex convict is light tanned, bald and has some facial hair. 

Except for your mention of it lacking famous actors this sounds very much like  the Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson movie Faster from 2010.

An ex-con goes on a series of apparently unrelated killings. He gets tracked by a veteran cop with secrets of his own and an egocentric hit man. 

